# printing the result once in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I just want to print the result array element in its right order and once, I used the barrier but it did nothing, I even wrote it after finalize and nothing happened here is the code:

```
MPI_Bcast(vec,W,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

col_count = myrank;
for(k=0; k<W; k++)
{
    res[col_count]+= vec[k]*matrix[k*W+col_count];
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("%d ",res[c]);
MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: It prints only once, per process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want everything to be in order, you should only print from one process. Which means you have to gather your whole result vector back to process 0, and then print it.

```
MPI_Gather (&(res[col_count]), 1, MPI_INT, res, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
for (int i=0 ; i<col_max ; ++i) {
  printf ("%f\n", res[i]);
}
```

Note that process 0 needs to have a full `res` vector (and you should take care to properly allocate it before calling `MPI_Gather`), but in your example all other processes only use `res[col_count]`, so you'd be better off allocating only one `int` for them.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for MPI_Comm_rank.  Then add a guard to only allow one specific rank to print.  Rank 0 is one obvious choice for printing.

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if(rank == 0) {
    printf ("Hello world! I'm rank %d\n", rank);
}
```